# Sig fig formatting display with variable sig figs

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am trying to display sig figs in a string and I have found the `'{:.2f}'.format(x)` style and it works great as long as I have the number of sig figs as an integer in the code, but I cannot seem to get this style of formatting to work if the number of sig figs is contained in a variable.  `2` works `sig=2` doesn't.  I have been trying to use the `%` along with `.format` to insert `sig` like this `'{:.%if}'.format(x) %sig'`, but it doesn't work.

I am sure there is a very simple elegant solution to this, but I cannot figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some sample input-outputs to make the question more clear.

Comment: The answer by `unutbu` is correct and probably best.  Your attempt could be correct pretty easily though:  `('{:.%if}'%sig).format(x)'` would probably work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually use string format substitution to supply parameters to the format string itself:

```
In [79]: '{:.{s}f}'.format(1.234, s=2)
Out[79]: '1.23'

In [80]: '{:.{s}f}'.format(1.234, s=3)
Out[80]: '1.234'
```

Comment: Just a note for users: for python2.6, this needs to be:  `'{0:.{s}f}'.format(1.234, s = 2)` (which will work with later versions of python as well).

Comment: I've gotten bit by version compatibility in python and when dealing with different compilers to not keep an eye out for these things :).  That said, good answer (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with old style string interpolation (% formatting) for those of us who like it so much:

```
>>> "%.*f"%(2,1.2345)
'1.23'
>>> "%.*f"%(3,1.2345)
'1.234'
```

But you should probably use the form proposed by @unutbu if you're using a newer version of python (2.6+)